# Shared authentification betwen Asp.Net web forms and angularJs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, authentication

Using AngularJs authentification, i want to add some asp.net pages and keep using the same authentification (angularJs authentification).
I try this code in code behind of asp.net pages to get current user but doesn't help (return null):

```
var userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

How to get current user in asp.net pages?

Answer (score 0):

From webAPIController, add User Authentication values in Cookie and use that Cookie values in AngularJS Controller using "$cookies" module.
you have add "angular-cookies.js" file to user cookie.

This is my AngularJS Controller request,

```
var request = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/api/LoginUser/AuthenticateUser",
                    params: { LoginUser: data }
                }).then(function successResult(successData) {
                    if (successData.status == "202") {
                       $scope.LoginUser.ErrorMsg = successData.data;
                    }
                    else {
                            var obj = JSON.parse(successData.data);
                            $scope.UserList = obj;

                            if (obj != null) {
                                UserService.isLogged = true;
                                window.location.href = "/WelcomeScreen";
                            }
                            else {
                                UserService.isLogged = false;
                                $scope.LoginId = "";
                                $scope.Password = "";
                                window.location.href = "/Login";
                            }                                            
                    }

public HttpResponseMessage AuthenticateUser(HttpRequestMessage request, string LoginUser)
{
//Authenticate user
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = UserName;
}
```

Now you can user Username in AngularJS JS file,
$cookies.get("UserName")

Comment: Can you explain by example please, the page login is in angularJs,